CodeIgniter 4-Nginx Server 404
I'm trying to make a website with VTiger using CodeIgniter 4, Composer with MySQL database
I made the installation following the instructions in CodeIgniter documentation, but I can't find the error. The problem is when I enter into the login page (this page works) and I write my access that is working because I don't get a bad credentials error. The website just shows me 404, previously I was getting 401 Unauthorized, but that changed when I edited my nginx conf file.
This is my nginx .conf file
server {
    root /var/www/html/mydomain.com/;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/mydomain.com.error.log debug;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html index.php;
    server_name mydomain.com;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }
    # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.2-fpm.sock;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    location ~ /\. {
        deny all;
    }

    listen [::]:443 ssl http2; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl http2; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    #include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    #ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    }

    server {
        if ($host = mydomain.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot
    server_name mydomain.com;
    listen [::]:80;
    listen 80;
    # return 404; # managed by Certbot
    }

I checked necessary extensionsfor PHP, here my php info PHP INFO
I know it's really hard find the issue, but maybe someone with more experience can help to fix it or to know where can I start If you need more info about my config, please let me know

Usually, any 404 error is unrelated to PHP extensions. Did you check whether the route you try to access really exists?

Hi Nico, yes the files are there, this is my tree path
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OywpsnaR4XRAdDHvYymsr6Gi8CNe8vLT/view?usp=sharing
I'm not sure is there a problem with the nginx .conf file or the location of archives

Please add all clarification to your question by editing it, not to the comment section and not through any external ressource

I was able to solve it on my own, after researching I found that unlike Apache, the routing configuration must be done manually for Nginx
location /vtigerest/ {
            alias /var/www/html/mydomain.com/vtigerest/;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /vtigerest/index.php;

    # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
    #
        location ~ \.php$ {
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.2-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
        }
    }

